# Flow of charge through metal wire

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge

It is the flow of charge that matters -- electrical current is *defined* as the flow of *charge*. " -person W

> [...] if the flow of charge is all that matters; and electrons with their charge attached are all that flow through metal wires then wouldn't
>   the electric current (defined as a the flow of charge) **equal** the
>   electrons flowing because they are all that flow through wires.
>   Protons don't flow through wires, *so how could the proton and it's
>   charge flow in the opposite direction of the electron flow if it
>   doesn't move ?*
>
> Does the proton charge get detached from the proton by the force of
>   the electron opposite from it.
>   - person M

If you believe this specific question has a answer on another thread, please do not downvote and put on hold. Instead let me know and I will see if it does, and if so I will either edit or remove this one.

Comment: Don't use unnecessary CAPS.... either use __bold__ or _italics_ to emphasize on something.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I didn't. I did. where did I miss.

Comment: Read this : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60854/87401 . Your question is a possible duplicate of this answer's question.

Comment: @Shubham not so. that question was about charge in general i.e. N+ liquid, mine is about a metal wire. but it was getting there.

Comment: I really can't tell what you are asking. Protons don't flow in wires. Electrons do flow in wires, but their actual function is to transport the potential along the wire by shaping the electromagnetic field trough the boundary conditions set by their high charge density. This is not an explanation that one can give on the basic level of your question. It requires a full understanding of Maxwell's equations and their solutions near such boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons have a drift velocity which is very small. But electrons pass the charge. They do not **flow** with a charge on it. It's like dominoes that fall. The energy wave propagates through the falling dominoes, but the dominoes don't translate much.

Also it doesn't matter who is propagating the charge. Electrons and protons and charged ions- all can do that.
If you say :

> proton and it's charge flow in the opposite direction of the electron flow

Then, net current would be 2 times the current due to flow of negative charge only or positive charge only.

And this is incorrect:

> proton charge get detached from the proton by the force of the electron opposite from it

Comment: `The energy wave propagates through the falling dominoes, but the dominoes don't translate much`- what does that mean? How does, according to you, the energy propagate? I'm not getting that.

Comment: it means that the electrons are more or less stationary and it just passes the charge with negligible translational motion @MAFIA36790

Comment: No; I'm talking about the energy.... how does it propagate?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 energy is the charge of the electron times the force applied to it (voltage). That way you can relate the energy to electrons. And that is just an example to make o.p understand better. You need not think too much in depth about it :)

Comment: ooh... I got the point. But still, it would be better to remember energy is not taken up electrons, passed to the next neighbourhood electrons and so on.... energy doesn't travel parallel to the flow of charges; it flows __perpendicular__ to the flow- that is the direction of Poynting vector.

Comment: @Shubham " proton charge get detached from the proton by the force of the electron opposite from it " I'm sure it is incorrect, but why.                    " But electrons pass the charge " that part is interesting but I don't see it's connection(mistakenly).

Comment: @MAFIA36790 "  energy doesn't travel parallel to the flow of charges; it flows perpendicular to the flow " so if that's true then how does the light bulb light up with the energy not getting to it because it's going perpendicular (up) from the flow of charge through the wire.

Comment: @MacR.: Nothing changes on how energy propagates, although. But, in fact, energy propagates in the direction of Poynting vector, the cross product of electric field and the magnetic field.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 I am a layperson and do not understand academic lingo.

Comment: @MacR.: Okay, energy doesn't flow _along_ the wire. It actually flows _into_ the wire from the EM field outside.

Comment: @Shubham fine I will, just answer me this about what you said "  They do not flow with a charge on it. " if not on it then when they flow where do they carry it(they are called carriers of charge aren't they). p.s. i have to go to sleep and work in the morning, i will accept your answer first thing in the morning when i see your response.

Comment: In simple lingo : these electrons in a wire stand in a line and they just pass they negative charge from one electron to another. But they donot move. Only charge moves and it moves from negative terminal of battery to positive terminal(current flows in opposite direction) through the wire. Also remember this: for current to flow charge must flow. Proton is moving or electron is moving or anything is moving..everything is unimportant... Charge must move - only thats important. If u still dont understand i give up brother

Comment: @Shubham I understand better. your explanation gave birth to a couple other questions for next time, now I have to go. p.s. +1 for     "  they just pass they negative charge from one electron to another. But they do not move."